# Crear variables indefinidas en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una duda en Javascript, pues quiero crear una lista select que al seleccionar uno de sus elementos, este se guarde y de esta forma se cree una variable independiente para ese valor, es decir

```
    function desplegar(){
   for (var=i;i<10000;i++){

 var valor[i]=[document.querySelector('[id=“desplegar”] option:checked').text];
          
       }
   }
```

Con el fin que al seleccionar cualquier opcion del select, esta se almacene primero en el espacio 1 de la variable *valor*, luego la próxima vez que seleccione una opción se guarde en la posición 2 de *valor*, y así poder almacenar múltiples respuestas y que al añadir una nueva, no se borre la anterior. El problema de esto es que aparte de que no funciona, al llegar al valor máximo de i, este dejará de servir. Hay alguna forma para crear variables instantáneamente al seleccionar una opción del select y que así se guarden todos los datos?

Comment: Tu estas reasignando la variable al declararla varias vecez, tu solo deberias poner el var una vez, es mas, el var ya esta desaconsejado, en su lugar deberias empezar a usar el let.

Comment: ¿Por qué no mejor hacer un push de cada valor recuperado a una variable que los almacene como array?, pues al momento dentro de ese ciclo cada que se obtiene un valor y se asigna el anterior se elimina, así declaras el vector por fuera del ciclo, lo llenas dentro del y lo lees fuera del ciclo

Comment: exacto eso deberia hacer @BetaM

Comment: Buenas, disculpen por haber mandado el anterior comentario como una respuesta, pero tengo una duda, cómo hago referencia a una respuesta?, pues la opción de comentarios no me deja referenciar la Respuesta de @BetaM. 
Con respecto a la duda planteada con anterioridad (la respuesta eliminada), que debería hacer?  Gracias por su servicio

Answer (score 2):

El problema con el código actual es que:

- Estás declarando a la variable `valor` dentro del contexto del ciclo, entonces por cada vuelta la variable es redeclarada esto nos lleva a que en cada iteración el valor asignado se pierde y se agina el nuevo es decir no lo va acumulando
- Cuando el ciclo termine la variable tendrá como valor asignado el generado en la última iteración.

Revisa este ejemplo (**que considero es la opción que deberías aplicar**):

```js
    let elementos = [];
    
    for (let inicio = 1; inicio<=5; inicio++) {
      elementos.push(inicio);
    }
    
    console.log(elementos);
```

- Declaro un vector fuera del contexto del ciclo
- Lleno el vector con los elementos que obtuve de la iteración por medio de `push`

Con una salida así:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

De esta manera logré acumular todos los elementos deseados en la variable y poder acceder a ellos fuera del ciclo.

Caso contrario (**esto es similar a lo que tienes al momento**).

Si solamente dentro del ciclo asigno el iterador a la variable y posterior la trato de recuperar obtendré el último valor generado.

```js
    let elementos = [];
    
    for (let inicio = 1; inicio<=5; inicio++) {
      elementos = inicio;
    }
    
    console.log(elementos);
```

Entonces una vez que con la primer opción propuesta vayas recuperando y almacenando las *respuestas* podrás iterarlas o acceder a alguna en específico por que están dentro de un array.